# Can countries prevent foreign corporations like Apple from acting as private police in their own territory?

Tags: corporations

Recently Apple has started [scanning](https://techcrunch.com/2021/08/05/apple-icloud-photos-scanning/) all the photos users have on their devices to detect possible child abuse, other corporations are already scanning all the content uploaded to the cloud. Therefore, without asking anyone, they have taken the responsibility to act as a private police on an international scale.

If people accept the principle, then how can they prevent those corporations from using the same mechanism to discreetly scan for political opinions? Can a limit to the police like duties taken by the corporation be imposed in a legal manner? I am not interested in legal approaches that could be taken in the US because this is the country of those corporations, I am interested in what could be done legally in other countries that find themselves subject to the action of foreign private police forces.

Related question:
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/71285/is-apple-scanning-user-content-for-child-abuse-a-violation-of-gdpr

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you try explaining it again? You seem to be afraid that countries will require Apple to act as private police, so you want countries to prevent it?

Comment: @PaulJohnson "You seem asking ..." Please don't play straw man arguments.

Comment: I'm not, I'm just trying to understand what it is that you are asking. What I wrote is my interpretation of your words. It doesn't make sense, which is why I'm asking for clarification. Obviously you meant something different.

Comment: Trivially, a country can stop e.g. Apple from acting as an agent of the police by just not taking crime reports from Apple. Is that what you want? Or are you talking about legal options for the *citizens* of the country? But that isn't what your title asks.

Comment: This is one of those Qs like ["can America nuke the world?"](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5927/18373). The real Q is whether countries would have any incentive in putting such obstacles in Apple's path when child-porn is almost universally reviled and laws against it almost always get tougher, everywhere see [e.g. developments in Germany](https://www.dw.com/en/germany-online-child-abuse-investigators-to-get-more-powers/a-52037583).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129140/discussion-on-question-by-fluidcode-can-countries-prevent-foreign-corporations-l). I moved the comments discussing the subject matter. Please use comments only to discuss whether the question should be reopened or how it can be improved. If you want to discuss the subject, please use chat or wait to post an answer if and when the question is reopened.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729 I guess you are referring to the description of the system that Apple recently released to save the face. That was released after this question was asked and in any case it is not very credible.

Answer (score 7):

In your example it seems you're not actually worried about police work, but about "big brother" type observation.

Countries can simply make it illegal* for cloud providers to access their customers' photos, or at least require them to ask for permission in a way that goes beyond not clicking a checkbox somewhere inside a nested settings menu.

Similarly, countries can make it illegal* for cloud providers to store photos in a way that can not be accessed by the company (on behalf of the government), if they want to go the other way.

If a country wants to allow scanning for only specific content, countries could task a regulatory body to approve specific automated algorithms, and require* that only approved scanning algorithms can be run over customer data. A country could also demand* that government provided scanning algorithms must be run over customer data.

Since companies are about making money "make it illegal", "require", or "demand" means imposing fines for non compliance.

Comment: It is not that simple. What you say is already illegal, but it seems that to circumvent those laws Apple and the other corporation decided to put in place mass investigations on their user. But who gave them the right to do that?

Comment: @FluidCode Rights in most countries are negative rather than positive. People (and companies) have the right to do things *unless explicitly banned* rather than the other way around. Laws granting you free speech for example are not actually giving you any right, but rather about limiting how the government can restrict speech. They have the right because they haven't been banned from doing so.

Comment: @user141592 We are talking about conducting mass investigations without the mandate of a judge. Are you sure this is not banned?

Comment: @FluidCode It would have to be tried in court to see if it falls under any existing law. However, laws banning things are often (intentionally) very narrow in scope, so it might not be. The technology to do this is also very new, so it's not unlikely that it doesn't fall under any existing law. There are laws banning the government from doing it, but until very recently no one else could conceivably do it so there was no reason to ban it.

Comment: @FluidCode: Exactly why is it illegal for Apple to access data that you have voluntarily chosen to place on their cloud platform?  Is there some contract forbidding them from doing so?  Perhaps you'd have a case if they searched data on your device, as it'd be akin to wiretapping, but even then it could be argued that you accepted the possibility when you bought an Apple device.

Comment: @jamesqf Did Apple users know what was going to happen when they bought the device? I don't know how this system will be deployed, but I suspect that with the OS update it will end up on devices that were bought a long time ago.

Comment: @FluidCode: and you can bet that if that's the case there will be a click-wrap agreement for new/updated [legal] terms on the update. Never seen that?

Comment: @jamesqf AFAIK they are not just scanning data on their cloud platform, but also data you hold in your hand which is not on their cloud platform.

Comment: @Fizz GDPR does not count clickwrap as consent, because it is not consent.

Comment: @user253751: If you're sure about this, you could make a nice Skeptics question. Here's a quote: "the GDPR-compliant way to obtain consumer consent is through a clickwrap agreement" https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/goodbye-browsewrap-hello-gdpr/

Comment: @FluidCode: A reasonably intelligent user should have realized that things of this sort were possible, given Apple's demonstrated pattern of behavior with apps, tracking, and such.  (And of course an intelligent user would not put possibly illegal content on ANY connected device in the first place.)

Comment: @jamesqf I don't know how it works in the US, but in my country by law it is not allowed to take advantage of the gullible. Furthermore humans can make mistakes or overlook something that for other is evident in a lot of different fields. If you accept the principle sooner or later you would find yourself in a similar situation in another context.

Comment: @user253751 On August 31st when you posted, and today when I reply, your comment was factually wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In most 'Liberal' nations, private citizens are allowed (even encouraged) to report crimes to police agencies. They are even allowed, within limits — private detective style — to look into the behavior of others to identify criminal behavior. There are, for example, a number of notable individuals and private groups which currently pose as young children online in order to trap pedophiles, groups which are usually tolerated by law enforcement officers.

Apple is a private company, and as such has the same circumscribed freedoms as private individuals and other private groups. The government has nothing much to do with their actions.

Currently, few laws or international agreements prohibit Apple or other companies from scanning your private information for crimes, political opinions, religious leanings, sexual orientation, or anything else. In fact, many companies — Google, Facebook, Amazon, etc — already do this as part of tailored marketing strategies. I believe the EU has put in effect some stricter privacy regulations, but I'm not up on the details. That is a political issue in and of itself, perhaps, because I'm not sure we want to give private mega-corporations that kind of clout. But that's a different question.

Comment: Not my DV (in fact I upvoted). The slight caveat is that users generally have to agree to such company policies, but it's [presently] really easy for companies to put that in the fine print of some [click-wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickwrap) agreement.

Comment: Re "your private information", by uploading it to Apple's cloud, haven't you voluntarily made it public?

Comment: I don't think that putting on the same level corporations and private citizens is right. Corporations have more power over the citizens private data, which should imply more responsibility.

Comment: @jamesqf Apple's scanner also scans photos which are stored on your cellphone and nowhere else. That's why there was a technical big deal with that whole "neural hash" and "private set intersection" stuff. They are protocols where Apple tries to determine if your phone contains contraband, without revealing anything that's on your phone if it's not contraband. Still, the fact that the contraband detection protocol is technically impressive, does not negate the fact that Apple is running a contraband detection protocol on your phone.

Comment: @jamesqf And no, information shared between two people, especially if one person only has it in an encrypted form they cannot decrypt, is not public by any reasonable definition!

Comment: @user253751: per that last comment... Careful of legal precedent, here. A phone is by definition a communication device which crosses public spaces. As such, they could be treated like cars and trucks, which (in the US) lack 4th amendment protections against search and seizure. If one has contraband in a car, it doesn't matter what security protocols one has implemented; if police have cause to pull you over, they can search for it and arrest you for it.

Comment: @user253751: If information is shared between two parties, then can't either party choose to disclose it?  (Barring some contract to the contrary, of course.) If it's encrypted in a form the second party (Apple) can't decrypt, then what's the problem?

Comment: @jamesqf You seem to argue that uploading an encrypted file to iCloud makes the encrpyted file public, and therefore it's okay for Apple to peek at the decrypted copy of the file on your phone for some reason. Am I with you so far?

Comment: @user253751: No, there are two distinct cases here. 1) You encrypt files and put them on the cloud.  Apple can look, because you've given them the file, but can't see what's in the file.  2) Apple accesses unencrypted stuff on your device.  You could call this wiretapping, but as an aware user, you should have known that Apple is prone to doing stuff like this.  It's like the old days of telephones, when there were operators and party lines, so there was always a possibility that a third party could listen to your conversation.  No expectation of privacy, IOW.

Comment: @jamesqf 3. You encrypt files and put them on the cloud but backdoor code on your device also sends an unencrypted copy to law enforcement just in case.

Comment: @user253751: But why would you buy a device like that, if you are going to be doing something illegal?  My point is that there is nothing that gives you an expectation of privacy, nor AFAIK has Apple ever made any contractual guarantee or expectation of privacy.  Now I'm not saying that it's OK for Apple to behave this way, but they do, so we have to deal with the real world.

Comment: @jamesqf Because all available devices do that. (They *will* if they don't already)

Comment: @user253751: That's simply not true.  I use a dumb phone that does nothing but voice & text.  (Because that's all I want from a phone.)  I have cameras that have no internet connectivity.  I have computers that are only rarely connected to the internet.  It would be no trouble at all to have one that was never connected.  I could put all my sensitive info on an SD chip, which would be easy to conceal...

Comment: @jamesqf So you are choosing not to put any information on your device, but you are still aware that if you do it will go to law enforcement.

Comment: @user253751: MAY rather than WILL.  But if I'm doing things that might draw the intention of law enforcement (or snoopy journalists, jealous SOs, or whatever), then I am going to be careful about leaving tracks behind me :-)